# Date value null in angularjs ajax request

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am newbie in angularjs. I have form and it has a date input box defined as follows.

```
<input type="text" name="due_date" ng-model='data.customer.due_date' id="due_date" >
```

I am using jquery date picker to pick the date and using yyyy/MM/dd format. When I save the form due_date shows null value.

Comment: can you show a sample, fiddle etc.

Comment: And how you are accessing

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with the jquery date picker control, but it's likely it gets built in a way that isn't setup to work with ng-model (angular wouldn't know exactly where to set/pull the date from)   You might get better success from : https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker if that is an option.

Comment: Try to include your `controller` so we can better pin down the issue.